# Force on current carrying wire in magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I was doing an experiment on the force on a current carrying wire in a magnetic field. I used an electric weight to register the magnetic force. When I used the force, current, and length of the wire to calculate the size of the magnetic field, I discovered that it is not constant. What is the cause of this? Attatched is a picture of our calculations and the experiment. Please ask questions if you need any clarifications. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that the scale readings are in g not kg as a magnetic field of 70 T is enormous!

A suggestion is that you might be using a highly non-uniform field.
The magnets are attracted to the current carrying conductor and so the balance pan moves relative to the fixed current carrying conductor.
As the force of attraction gets larger the magnets move up more and possibly the current carrying conductor is now in a region of higher magnetic field.

To check this idea you need to start (no current) with the current carrying conductor in different positions relative to the magnets.